# Button export in a datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to add a single export button at the top of a datagrid. My biggest problem is to be able to add commandParameter, with all the datagrid's selected items.

I already did it for the contextMenu, but I need to add a button doing the same think.

Here's the code :

```
<Grid>
    <Controls:MetroContentControl>
        <Expander Header="HeaderExpa" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" IsExpanded="True" IsEnabled="True">
            <Grid Name="Namegrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ressource}" Name="NameDatagrid">
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="AlignBottomColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource AzureDataGridColumnHeader}" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <!--Description-->
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem 
                                Header="HeaderContextMenu"
                                Command="{ Binding CommandExport }"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems}"
                            />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </Expander>
    </Controls:MetroContentControl>
</Grid>
```

How can I add this specific button to my datagrid ? I try a few things, like adding

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderCheckbox">
    <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Focusable="false" 
                Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                Visibility="Visible" 
                Width="200"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

right after `<DataGrid.Resources>`, adding a button before the datagrid declaration, most of the time, the button does just not appear.

Thank's a lot for your help :)

Comment: You want the button to be inside the data grid or could it be outside?

Comment: If I can add the datagrid selected item in parameters, I don't really care about where the button is (still need to be on the top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add one more row definition to your grid panel and then just add the button to that particular row (the one above your grid) and then use this:

```
<Grid Name="Namegrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=NameDatagrid, Path=SelectedItems}"/>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ressource}" Name="NameDatagrid"/>
    </Grid>
```

PS: Please provide a name to your DataGrid and use it for ElementName inside the button. And the button should be above the DataGrid control itself, not inside. Make sure you mention Grid.Row="1" for DataGrid also.

Comment: I add `<Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Button CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=NameGris, Path=SelectedItems}"/>
                    </Grid>` right after `</Grid.RowDefinitions>` and it doens't change anything, no button "appear"